# convert from SQL to JPA query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have this SQL Query

```
SELECT 'variable'                CATEGORY,
       'Referral Received in '    VARIABLE,
       SUM (OPD)                 OPD,
       SUM (IPD)                 IPD,
       SUM (DC)                  DAYCARE,
       SUM (PROC)                PROCEDURE,
       SUM (SUR)                 SURGERY,
         SUM (NVL (OPD, 0))
       + SUM (NVL (IPD, 0))
       + SUM (NVL (DC, 0))
       + SUM (NVL (PROC, 0))
       + SUM (NVL (SUR, 0))      AS TOTAL
  FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN B.ID = 1 THEN 1 END     AS OPD,
               CASE WHEN B.ID = 2 THEN 1 END     AS IPD,
               CASE WHEN B.ID = 3 THEN 1 END     AS DC,
               CASE WHEN B.ID = 4 THEN 1 END     AS PROC,
               CASE WHEN B.ID = 5 THEN 1 END     AS SUR
          FROM REF_TB_APP_TRANSACTIONS A, REF_VW_VISIT_TYPE B
         WHERE REQ_VISIT_TYPE = B.ID AND A.TO_EST_CODE = 20068)
```

I want to convert it to JPA query
I tried this but it gives me many errors (This is first time to me to write JPA query )

```
SELECT 'variable'                CATEGORY," + 
            "                 'Referral Received in '    VARIABLE," + 
            "                 SUM (OPD)                 OPD," + 
            "                 SUM (IPD)                 IPD," + 
            "                 SUM (DC)                  DAYCARE," + 
            "                 SUM (PROC)                PROCEDURE," + 
            "                 SUM (SUR)                 SURGERY," + 
            "                    SUM (NVL (OPD, 0))" + 
            "                 + SUM (NVL (IPD, 0))" + 
            "                  + SUM (NVL (DC, 0))" + 
            "                  + SUM (NVL (PROC, 0))" + 
            "                  + SUM (NVL (SUR, 0))      AS TOTAL" + 
            "             FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN B.id = 1 THEN 1 END     AS OPD," + 
            "                          CASE WHEN B.id = 2 THEN 1 END     AS IPD," + 
            "                          CASE WHEN B.id = 3 THEN 1 END     AS DC," + 
            "                         CASE WHEN B.id = 4 THEN 1 END     AS PROC," + 
            "                          CASE WHEN B.id = 5 THEN 1 END     AS SUR" + 
            "                    FROM model.central.RefTbAppTransaction A, model.central.RefVwVisitType B" + 
            "                   WHERE A.reqVisitType.id = B.id AND A.toEstCode = :toEstCode)
```

this tow entities `RefTbAppTransaction` and `RefVwVisitType`

If there any help this is one error

```
[ERROR] 2021-03-31 11:02:07 [] ErrorTracker - line 1:1016: unexpected token: CASE
[ERROR] 2021-03-31 11:02:07 [] ErrorTracker - line 1:1016: unexpected token: CASE
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: CASE
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromRange(HqlBaseParser.java:1519) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1363) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1063) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:319) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
```

this another

```
[ERROR] 2021-03-31 11:02:07 [] ErrorTracker - line 1:1284: expecting EOF, found ')'
[ERROR] 2021-03-31 11:02:07 [] ErrorTracker - line 1:1284: expecting EOF, found ')'
antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting EOF, found ')'
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:709) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
```

I think it's syntax error or some keywords not defined in JPA

Comment: Please post your stacktraces as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: How to write jpa method for this query? SELECT * FROM do_not_track WHERE (user_id=7 ) AND ('2022-06-25' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) OR ('2022-06-30' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date);

Answer (score 1):

From your stacktrace it seems like your query is interpreted as hql (see `HqlBaseParser`). If your want to write sql instead of hql you need to use `createNativeQuery` instead of `createQuery`.

Please see https://vladmihalcea.com/the-jpa-entitymanager-createnativequery-is-a-magic-wand/ for some examples of how to use `createNativeQuery`.

Comment: How can I convert it my SQL to JPA I dont want hql